# SQL Server 2008, recovering my password / login to management studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

On Windows 7 machine which I acquired, another user had previously installed SQL Server 2008 on to it under their user name.

Now, from my account when I try to start the Management Studio, I can NOT seem to connect to my local Server. I have tried:

`(local)` and `CName\InstanceName`
both with the `Windows Authentication` and  `SQL Server Authentication` (I tried "sa" and "sa" for SQL server authentication)

I keep getting the same error:

`Login failed for user 'foo', (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)`

Is there a way I can add new account with out logging in?

Or, do I have to uninstall and reinstall the whole darn thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the other user installed SQL Server he/she specified a SQL Server administrator account.
The easy way out in that situation is to use the button `Add Current User` which means that you need to log in as that user to be able to administrate your SQL Server installation.
Local administrator can be an admin user in SQL Server but in SQL Server 2008 that is not the default behavior, it has to be configured.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280562.aspx

If SQL Server is installed in Mixed Mode Authentication he/she also specified a password for the `sa` account. If you could get a hold of that password you would be good to go.

You can not add a new account without logging in.

If you can not get access to SQL Server, the only way I see is to uninstall/install.

Comment: thanks, that is what I ended up having to do, i.e. uninstall/install. It works fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging onto the machine locally using the local machine's Administrator account, and using integrated Windows Authentication?